# Error by execution varnishtop with some parameters

Tags: varnish

I'm trying to debug my varnish configuration, but when I execute

```
varnishtop -i TxUrl
```

I get this error:

```
-i: "RxUrl" matches zero tags
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long search, we found this:

https://www.varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2014-September/024019.html

TxURL is named BereqURL in varnish 4

If you use varnish 4, the command should be:

```
varnishtop  -i  BereqURL
```